# Как выбрать допустим 2-ое фото из файла и отправить его?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу телеграмм бота, ему отправляют фото и он сохраняет их в папку, мне нужно чтобы принажатие определенной кнопки он все файлы что в ней есть отправлял альбомом пользователю, но название файлов под которыми сохраняет бот - я не знаю, как это реализовать ? и возможно-ли?

Comment: В заголовке одно, в вопросе совсем другое.

Comment: Да, это как-то возможно реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, что бы увидеть, какие файлы есть в папке, можно использовать модуль `os`, с помощью него, можно выполнить команду `dir` (если вы на `Windows`)

```py
import os

def getFileNames(nameDir, delTemp=True):
    os.system(f"dir {nameDir} /b > temp.txt")

    fileNames=[]

    with open("temp.txt", encoding="cp866") as f:
        fileNames=f.read().splitlines()

    if delTemp:os.system("del temp.txt")
    return fileNames
```